# Contar quantidade de registros de consulta MySQL no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

Fiz o código abaixo para contar a quantidade de registros, mas ele me conta 1 a 1, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para somar estes registros e chamar com um echo.

```
    ?>  
            <?php
$sql="SELECT id FROM processo";
$return = $conexao->query( $sql );

if ( $return == false ) {
        echo $conexao->error;
        }

    while ($registro = $return->fetch_array()) {

        $id=$registro["id"];

        $result=count($sql);
        echo $result;
    }

?>
```

[image: Demonstração do código acima]

Comment: Tem uma tag de fechamento logo no inicio do codigo, isso não está errado?

Answer (score 2):

Se a sua consulta é apenas para contar o **total** de registros, você pode fazer uma consulta bem econômica segundo [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_count.asp):

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS result FROM processo');
$total = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Agora, se além do total você também precisa que sejam retornados algumas informações, você pode fazer a mesma consulta acima, apenas alterando um detalhe: colunas você substitui pelas colunas que quer. Por exemplo: id, name, content, etc:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(colunas) AS result FROM processo');
$total = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $data['total'];
```

Algumas respostas informaram while ou consultas com *. **Cuidado!** Consultas com * tendem a utilizar recursos desnecessários, tornando a query lenta e com resultados indesejados.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT id FROM processo";
$return = $conexao->query( $sql );

if ( $return == false ) {
        echo $conexao->error;
        }

    echo'Qtd. registros: ' . count(mysql_fetch_array($return, MYSQL_ASSOC));

?>
```

Comment: ficou em branco

Comment: Tem dados no teu array?

Answer (score 0):

consegui com o seguinte codigo que um amigo da faculdade desenrolou

```
    $sql="SELECT dt_faturamento FROM processo WHERE 
    dt_faturamento='faturado'";

$return = $conexao->query( $sql );

        if ( $return == false ) {
                echo $conexao->error;
                }

        $result = 0;

        while($registro = $return->fetch_array()) {
            $result++;
        }

        echo $result;

    ?>`:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(id) AS qtdRegistros FROM processo";
echo $conexao->query( $sql )->fetch_object()->qtdRegistros;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar este método

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "Processos: ".$num_rows;
```