# Contar numero de registros em uma tabela MySql com PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, contador

Gente, eu tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela chamada "usuarios", e eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para, através de PHP, contar quantos registros existem nessa tabela, e logo dar um 'echo' para mostrar essa quantidade na página. Por favor me ajudem!!

Comment: Existem algumas perguntas que abordam esse assunto: [Contar quantidade de registros de consulta MySQL no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232266/contar-quantidade-de-registros-de-consulta-mysql-no-php)

Answer (score 1):

Só fazer dessa forma aqui.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado = count($sql);
echo $resultado;
```

Comment: Esse count aí do resultado vai retornar 1, não? Já que o select já tá com count...

Comment: agora eu arrumei a consulta, tava errado mesmo

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from tabela");
$resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $resultado['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz uma consulta no banco, você pode passar o Count:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit WHERE calories > 100";
```

Answer (score 0):

O PHP possui uma função só pra contar as linhas sem usar o `Count(*)` que é o `mysqli_num_rows()`. Com isso você consegue reaproveitar o resultado da query.

```
$QUERY = "SELECT * AS Quantidade FROM BancoA.tabelaA";
$executa_query = mysqli_query($conexao, $QUERY);
$conta_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($executa_query);
echo $conta_linhas;
```